# Use custom HTML writer in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I use a different `HTMLTranslator` than the one that ships with Sphinx in `sphinx.writers.html`?

Specifically, I want to modify the method `depart_desc_signature`. I can't modify Sphinx itself because the help files are being developed with others and need to compile correctly with standard Sphinx.

I know Sphinx supports:

- extension modules: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/appapi.html
- custom builders: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/builderapi.html

Comment: Adding a custom filter to sphinx's instance of jinja2 would also work, but I also don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected answer is no longer valid in recent versions of Sphinx.  I asked on the sphinx-users mailing list, and
Jean Abou Samra was kind enough to give me the following explanation and example code that can be put into conf.py:

The setup() function in the configuration file takes the application
object and can mutate it. For example, this code in conf.py would
interpret all emphasis markup as bold:

```
from sphinx.writers.html import HTMLTranslator

class MyTranslator(HTMLTranslator):
     def visit_emphasis(self, node):
         self.visit_strong(node)
     def depart_emphasis(self, node):
         self.depart_strong(node)

def setup(app):
     app.set_translator('html', MyTranslator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify an html translator by defining an `html_translator_class` in `conf.py`.

For example,

```
html_translator_class = 'html2.HTMLTranslator'
```

This does not play nice with mathjax though, so if `html2` is otherwise a copy of `sphinx.writers.html`, you need to explicitly add calls to mathjax to HTMLTranslator:

```
def visit_displaymath(self, node):
    import sphinx.ext.mathjax
    sphinx.ext.mathjax.html_visit_displaymath(self, node)
def depart_displaymath(self, node):
    return
def visit_math(self, node):
    import sphinx.ext.mathjax
    sphinx.ext.mathjax.html_visit_math(self, node)
def depart_math(self, node):
    return
```